# how to adjust width and color at the sime time when doing an animation with CSS?

Tags: html, css

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>page moves</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="leftdiv"


            <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
        </div>

        <div class="rightdiv">
            <a href="#">MENU</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
body
{
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
div
{
     display: inline-block;
     position: absolute;
     width: 50%;
     height: 100%;
}
.leftdiv
{    
     background-color: black;
     left: 0;
}
.rightdiv
{
     background-color: firebrick;
     right: 0;
}
a
{
     position: relative;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     top: 50%;
}
.leftdiv a
{
     color: crimson;
}
.rightdiv a
{
     color: black;
}
.leftdiv:hover
{
     width: 75%;
     transition-duration: 0.9s;
}
```

So the problem is that when i hover the div with the class "leftdiv" the "a" moves but the background color on the div with class "leftdiv" doens't keep up with it why??

Comment: I would maybe add the transition property to the  element without hover. And then on hover you change the actual color and width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you want to change the z-index, which will make the element overlap another. You can read about z-index here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

By changing the z-index of `.leftdiv` to 1, it will make it have a higher layer than the `.rightdiv`. I have added it to `.leftdiv:hover` , but it can also be done directly on `.leftdiv`

```css
body
{
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
div
{
     display: inline-block;
     position: absolute;
     width: 50%;
     height: 100%;
}
.leftdiv
{    
     background-color: black;
     left: 0;
}
.rightdiv
{
     background-color: firebrick;
     right: 0;
}
a
{
     position: relative;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     top: 50%;
}

.leftdiv a
{
     color: red;
}
.rightdiv a
{
     color: black;
}
.leftdiv:hover
{
     width: 75%;
    z-index: 1;
     transition-duration: 0.9s;
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <div class="leftdiv">


            <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
        </div>

        <div class="rightdiv">
            <a href="#">MENU</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

For more help on transitions and CSS animations, I found this free course quite helpful: https://scrimba.com/course/gcssanimations

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes!! it really did, thanks so much dude :D appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

When you want to move the div over another then you should use `z-index` for this. Greater the number you will see that background on the front.

Considering there are no other `z-index` value used in you code so you can use `z-index:1;` and this will resolve your issue.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.leftdiv {
  background-color: black;
  left: 0;
}

.rightdiv {
  background-color: firebrick;
  right: 0;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  top: 50%;
}

.leftdiv a {
  color: crimson;
}

.rightdiv a {
  color: black;
}

.leftdiv:hover {
  width: 75%;
  transition-duration: 0.9s;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>page moves</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="leftdiv">


    <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
  </div>

  <div class="rightdiv">
    <a href="#">MENU</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: nonoo, what i want is to the leftdiv background overlap the rightdiv one, with that it doenset work, did u understand now?

Comment: Mean on hover whatever color you have on right it same color should have it in left ?

Comment: what i want is to keep the black color

Comment: Sorry I am not understanding it! :(

Comment: so basically i am trying to make the leftdiv popup using the hover function and making it 75% width as it was only 50% as the other div (the rightdiv) and when it transforms to get bigger(to the 75%width) the background-color doesnt do the same thing and thats the problem because if u see when u hover on the leftdiv the letters move and the div moves aswell(u can see that in the inspector) but the background doesnt overlap the other div background-color

Comment: OMG! sorry check my answer now, I got it now you want the left image to hover on top of right one? `div` is block element and if you want to move over another element then you have to use `z-index` property that to high number, I have used `1` since there are no other positive value to override with.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things are going on here. Position Relative is used on the parent and absolute on the left div. This is to allow the overlap to happen. Transition effect is added to the unhovered element and not just on hover. On hover all the properties change. Note they must exist on the unhovered class and on the hovered class in order for the effect to appear.

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
}

section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.left, .right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 20;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.left:hover {
   width: 70%;
   color: white;
   background: green;
}

.right {
  margin-left: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</section>
```

Comment: i run ur script now and it worked, thats it, thanks!!, i was just wondering what the "transition: all 1s ease-in-out;" does :D if u could explain me pls

Comment: If you don't have any transition effect the change will just happen without any smooth transition. It will be blue now and instantly green. That's not very pleasant to look at. Therefore, I added some transition properties in the short form syntax. If my answer was helpful to you, please consider accepting it as answer.